# Get the count of employee code in a new dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have my data of employee codes and I want to take out the count of them -

```
data = [[5],[3344],[5],[443],[22303],[1121],[3344],[1121],[5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['emp_codes'])
df

emp_codes
0   5
1   3344
2   5
3   443
4   22303
5   1121
6   3344
7   1121
8   5
```

I have taken their count -

```
df.groupby(['emp_codes'])['emp_codes'].count()

5        3
443      1
1121     2
3344     2
22303    1
```

I want them to store in a new dataframe, my output should be  -

```
emp_codes  count
5           3
443         1
1121        2
3344        2
22303       1
```

please help me to get this OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  df_group = df.groupby(['emp_codes'])['emp_codes'].count().to_frame() #convert series into pandas dataframe
  df_group.columns = ['count']  # rename the column as count the output that you want
  df_group.reset_index()

  #op 
    emp_codes   count
   0    5       3
   1    443     1
   2    1121    2
   3    3344    2
   4    22303   1
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of your `.count()` at the end is a pandas *Series*. You can do [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) so that the employee codes becomes a column, but since `emp_codes` already exists as the name of the series (the values), give the existing values a new name, like 'counts'. That turns it into a dataframe:

```py
emp_counts = df.groupby(['emp_codes'])['emp_codes'].count().reset_index(name='count')
emp_counts

   emp_codes  count
0          5      3
1        443      1
2       1121      2
3       3344      2
4      22303      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[5],[3344],[5],[443],[22303],[1121],[3344],[1121],[5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['emp_codes'])
df=df.groupby(['emp_codes'])['emp_codes'].count()
df=df.reset_index(name="count") #you can keep your preferred name
df
```